# How to Read PHP Inside Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do I get values of HTML form value and pass it in PHP code inside javascript?
I need to call a PHP function inside a javascript.
Please kindly help me fix my code.
Thank you very much.

```
<script>
function Send() {
var abc="<?php   echo mail_message.val();  //Email functionality here.. ?>";
document.write(abc);
}
</script>

<body>
<form>
<label class="email_label" for="mail_message">Message</label>
<textarea rows="7" cols="78" name="mail_message" id="mail_message">Enter your message here...</textarea>
<form>
</body>
```

Comment: what error does that code give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs before your JavaScript gets loaded, so if you need to send data to PHP you need an AJAX request:

```
$.post('script.php', {
    value: $('#mail_message').val()
}, function() {
    // success?
});
```

Your `script.php` will then read `$_POST['value']` and process it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the advice, but can you please show me a more complete example? Actually the PHP function that I need to call inside the javascript is a PHP email functionality, so I don't want to move to another page. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by complete example? What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use javascript `val()` in php syntex

instead use the following code to get the php value in javascript

```
<script>
function Send() {
   var abc=document.getElementById('mail_message').value;
   document.write(abc);
}
</script>
```

Comment: the PHP code that i want to put inside the Javascript function is PHP Email functionality. Thanks

Comment: So you have to call external php function to this.
So that your email process will be done.
`<?php mail(); ?>`

this will get the mail function in javascript;